# Bootstrap median CI for non normal data in matlab

Tags: confidence-interval, matlab, bootstrap, median

I would like to find CI from the median value for non normal data (heavy tail to one side). I read about the bootstrap method and would like to implement it using the `bootci` function in matlab. I have 2 questions:

1. What does the 95%CI from the median mean? How many of future measurements are likely to be inside the CI?
2. How many bootstrap samples would you use and why? I have more than 1000 samples (in some cases even 9000) and I know that the theoretical answer is as many samples as I can but I'm interested in a practical low limit of this number so the computation time will be reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

> What does the 95%CI from the median mean?

The 95% CI means exactly what all confidence intervals mean; that if you were to re-run the sampling process, and recompute the CI multiple times, the true median of the underlying data generation process would be contained in the CI 95% of the time. Now, this is not *exactly* correct since you are using the bootstrap, but it's approximately correct.

> How many of future measurements are likely to be inside the CI?

This cannot be said without further knowledge of the underlying data generation process (probability distribution) and the number of samples. I recommend a simulation study to investigate this. In a Bayesian framework it is somewhat more straightforward to compute predictive distributions (which is essentially what you seem to be looking for). I recommend looking into this.

> How many bootstrap samples would you use and why? I have more than 1000 samples (in some cases even 9000) and I know that the theoretical answer is as many samples as I can but I'm interested in a practical low limit of this number so the computation time will be reasonable.

Again, I recommend a simulation study to figure this out.

Comment: Those are good points, what is also worth mentioning is: what kind of simulation do you recommend? What would be the procedure? "Conduct a simulation." may have multiple meanings and be differently understood by different people (possibly example would help).

Comment: I also don't actually know what kind of simulation do I need to do. Could you clarify?

Comment: Can you comment on how exactly the use of the bootstrap affects the interpretation of the CI as you stated it?

Comment: @AR_ to estimate the MCMC error of the bootstrap, specifically the error due to running too few computational iterations, you must simulate data according to some fixed model. You can even use a single bootstrapped iteration of your dataset as a simulation, then calculate a bootstrapped CI from that. The invested work is substantial, but you must ensure you have achieved a certain level of precision so that each reported digit, hopefully no more than 3, has no MCMC error.